# Как запушить проект в чужой репезиторий?

Tags: git, github

Cделал git remote удаленного репезитория. Там есть 2 ветки (master и dev), после команды git push origin dev выходит "Everything up-to-date". Тут в стеке нашел похожий вопрос но там написано надо сделать git pull, ну что ок сделал и что потом?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2

Answer (score 0):

> после команды git push origin dev выходит "Everything up-to-date"

буквальный перевод: «всё обновлено».

это означает, что коммит, на который указывает та «ветка» (ветка/branch в программе *git* — это всего лишь указатель на коммит), которая у вас локально является текущей, **уже имеется** в хранилище, которое у вас локально называется «origin», причём он достижим по истории из того коммита, на который указывает «ветка» `dev` в удалённом хранилище (а скорее всего это вообще один и тот же коммит).

для того, чтобы можно было отправить **что-то новое** в удалённое хранилище, это новое нужно сначала создать (внести изменения и закоммитить их).